# Implicit operator to convert string input parameter to custom class using specflow

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, specflow

I've created a class to convert specflow parameters to custom class

```
public class KeyphraseState
{
    private Dictionary<string, bool> Keyphrase = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
    {
        { "displayed", true },
        { "not displayed", false }
    };

    private string Phrase;
    private bool State;

    public KeyphraseState(string text)
    {
        this.Phrase = text;
        this.State = GetState(this.Phrase);
    }

    private bool GetState(string phrase)
    {
        return Keyphrase[phrase];
    }

    public static implicit operator KeyphraseState(string text)
    {            
        return new KeyphraseState(text);
    }
}
```

Then I'm trying to use it in step definitions like

```
    [When(@"link is (.*) on the page")]
    public void WhenLinkIs(string status)
    {
        KeyphraseState st = status;
        // ...
    }
```

and it works great. But when I try to use it in step constructors

```
    [When(@"link is (.*) on the page")]
    public void WhenLinkIs(KeyphraseState status)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

then I have an error message ***Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'KeyphraseState'***

Can anybody explain if it is possible to use ***implicit operator*** in that case, or any other ways to implement such conversion?

Answer (score 1):

In SpecFlow there is a feature called 'Step Argument Transformation'. Is transforms you value from your step in the scenario to the type of your parameter in your step binding method.

Documentation and examples are here: http://specflow.org/documentation/Step-Argument-Conversions/

Comment: Andreas, many thanks for your answer. I shall try transformations and add a comment here if I succeed.